# Angular directive link() function receiving inconsistent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
"use strict";

angular.module("foo")
    .directive("breadcrumbs", function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: false,
        templateUrl: '/js/shared/directives/breadcrumbs.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn){
            console.debug(scope.parent);
            ...
```

Sometimes `scope.parent` is the scope of the current controller, sometimes it's `$rootScope`. I've discovered that when my custom directive is used like this:

```
<breadcrumbs></breadcrumbs>
```

it receives the controller scope, but when used with ng-if:

```
<breadcrumbs ng-if="searchData"></breadcrumbs>
```

it receives a new scope nested within the controller scope.

How do I write my directive to always receive the controller scope without resorting to any hackery (such as adding `ng-if="true"`)?

Update: I've corrected the description of the problem. The issue is that I get scopes at different levels of nesting depending on whether `ng-if` is used, regardless of whether `scope: false` or `scope: true` was used.

Comment: See this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if the directive is in context of a controller scope, you'll never receive `$rootScope` as the scope of directive.
When you use `ng-if`, you are receiving a prototypically inherited child scope (of the immediate parent scope, in this case the controller) created by `ng-if` becuase your directive has `scope: false` (which means pass in the closest scope instead of creating one)

You can always request a prototypically inherited child scope by setting `scope:true` or an isolated scope via `scope:{}`.

Answer (score 1):

What `ng-if=true` dose is create a new scope for your element.
You could achive that by changing the parameter

From

```
scope: false
```

To

```
scope: true
```